# Why are my form fields not aligning horizontally?

Tags: wordpress, html, css

I am using the Themify builder and I created a small form in a text block in the builder.

There is unintentional gap above the fields. You can view it live [here](http://testwebsitepage.club/offer/).

HTML:

```
<form action="contact_info.php" method="get">
    Loan Calculator
        <select class="form-inline">
            <option value="1000">$1,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="2000">$2,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="5000">$5,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="7500">$7,500 Loan</option>
            <option value="10000">$10,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="12000">$12,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="15000">$15,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="17000">$17,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="20000">$20,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="25000" selected="selected">$25,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="30000">$30,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="40000">$40,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="50000">$50,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="60000">$60,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="70000">$70,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="80000">$80,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="90000">$90,000 Loan</option>
            <option value="100000">$100,000 Loan</option>
        </select>
        <select class="form-inline">
            <option value="1">1 Year</option>
            <option value="2">2 Years</option>
            <option value="3">3 Years</option>
            <option value="4">4 Years</option>
            <option value="5" selected="selected">5 Years</option>
            <option value="6">6 Years</option>
            <option value="7">7 Years</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="form-inline">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.form-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: don't leave white space between both ... try `</select><select>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi please remove `<br>` tag between `<select>` in your code and your form fields will be shown as you want. `<br>` tag forces to break the line, that is why see such gaps.

Comment: those <br> tags are getting added automatically. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

On your demo page, there are `<br>` tag after every element in the form, please remove that.

Comment: those <br> tags are getting added automatically. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.
Wordpress adds `<br>` tags automatically if there is whitespace between form tags.
I removed all the whitespaces between every single tag and the problem was solved.